# Jest: How should I mock a class function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Good evening!

I'm trying to get my head around mocking in general, and this seems like a good case for it.

I have a **class** that handles image loading and keeps track of said images using an alias (e.g., `this._imgLoaded[path] = image`)

```
export default class Loader {

    // Constructor and what not

    _loadImage(path) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let image = new Image();
          image.src = path;
          image.onload = () => resolve(image);
          image.onerror = () =>
            reject(new Error("Image is not defined. Unable to load it."));
        });
      }

      async loadImage(path, alias) {
        const newPath = this._enrichRelativePath(path);
        let image;
        try {
          image = await this._loadImage(newPath);
        } catch (error) {
          // log and rethrow
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        }

        // cache the loaded image:
        this._imgLoaded[newPath] = image;

        if (alias) {
          this._imgAlias[alias] = newPath;
        }
      }
    }
```

I think that in order to unit test this, I have to create a mock function for `_loadImage` and make it return something.

What would be the best way to do so, while **keeping the other functions intact**?

As a side note, I'm using ES6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work with prototype (**__mocks__/loader.js**):

```
let Loader = require.requireActual("../src/loader.js");

Loader.prototype._loadImage = function() {
  return "test";
};

module.exports = Loader;
```

And then, in the test file (**__tests__/loader.test.js**):

```
import Loader from "loader";
jest.setMock("loader", require("../__mocks__/loader"));

test("Something", () => {
  expect.assertions(1);

  const loader = new Loader();

  expect(loader._loadImage()).toBe("test");
});
```